# endIconTint in TextInputLayout is not working

Tags: android, input, material-ui, android-textinputlayout

I'm creating a login form with `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` but toggle password icon always show in white no matter which color I assign to it as `endIconTint`. I have tested this on

> Android 6
> Android 10

both show the same results.

Here is my Form when I use `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` as a style in `TextInputLayout`. It seems like its not showing drawable but that's not the case its not visible as drawable & input field background color is white. When I click on the end it toggle password.
[image]

**Here is the form when I use `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox`**

[image]

And here is my code you can see I'm currently assigning black color to the `endIconTint`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_til"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="20"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:endIconTint="@color/black"
        app:helperText="required*"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/username_til"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_key">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_tiet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="20" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I cross verified color from the `color.xml` file and tried other colors too but icon always appear as white. Please let me know what is wrong here or is it a bug?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already specify `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` so you don't require to set `passwordToggleEnabled` anymore.

Remove this from `TextInputLayout` and it resolve your issue.

> app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

Comment: oh my bad, I added this earlier and forgot to remove. thanks